# drop columns with negative values in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix;

```
structure(c(1, -2, 1, 2, -2, 1, 3, 2, 1,4,5,6), .Dim = c(3L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c","d")))
```

I want to drop all columns that have negative value and return a matrix with only "c" and "d" columns. I tried `subset(a, a<0)` but it gives the following error:

```
Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on the logical matrix, negate it and use that to subset the columns

```
m1[,!colSums(m1 <0)]
#     c d
#[1,] 3 4
#[2,] 2 5
#[3,] 1 6
```